# What’s the difference between normal, hard, and hardcore mode in Another World: 20th Anniversary Edition?

Tags: another-world

The 20th anniversary edition of *Another World* has three difficulty levels:

- Normal Mode
- Hard Mode
- Hardcore Mode

What’s the difference between each difficulty level?

Comment: Checking the internetz I couldn't find a comprehensive list of differences. I also saw that there are more worms at the beginning of the game, enemies use charged shots more often, and timed parts are faster (water filling part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer has been provided by [zabeus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/187494/zabeus) from [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/323617/what-s-the-difference-between-normal-hard-and-hardcore-mode-in-another-world#comment461006_323617):

> So far I've found differences in the number of checkpoints, and the length of time that energy shields last. Hard difficulty should be identical to the original game.